# SQL SELECT all from large table in groups of set size

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This probably a very simple thing to do however I am not very well rounded in SQL Server, TSql, or even normal SQL for that matter.

I need to retrieve all records from a very large table (2 Million Records) and I am using the extracted data elsewhere as a tab delimited file.

I am writing a stored procedure to get this information, however all 2 million records is far too large so I need to return the data back with multiple select statements using a row limit (@BatchSize) set by the user.

The PK on this particular table is not sequential, therefore using a WHERE BETWEEN at the end is not ideal as each Select call returns a different number of records. And setting SELECT TOP (@BatchLimit) within a loop will just return the same X records over and over.

Is there a way I can get it to return @BatchLimit # of records then continue on from where it left off?  It sounds like a job for a cursor, but as someone who has never used a cursor before I am unsure. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You can leverage OFFSET FETCH for this type of thing. Here is a great article on the topic. https://sqlperformance.com/2015/01/t-sql-queries/pagination-with-offset-fetch

Comment: I'd would think using SSIS was an easier way to produce the file.

Comment: Are you trying to create multiple files (i.e. break down the 2 million into chunks based on user input)? If not then I'm not sure why you would use pagination. If you are then a while loop with the OFFSET FETCH @SeanLange mentioned should take care of it for you.

Comment: Thank you for this. I was unaware of the OFFSET FETCH, However, I am unable to use it as I am on an old version of SQLServer :(.

I think I have decided to try it out with a TOP(@BatchSize) and a WHERE id > @LastId. I will try to pull out the last id from each select and go from there, Offset would have been better though

Comment: You should tag the version of SQL you are on.  If you are putting the data in a delimited file you should be able to read the last value from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to share a SQL snippet that I use for splitting large queries into batches.

```
--OPTION 1: Select single part of the batch
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
DECLARE @batch TINYINT = 10

;WITH LargeTable AS(
SELECT  RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  c1.object_id)  --ORDER BY Primary Key
        ,c1.*
FROM    sys.columns as c1
        CROSS APPLY sys.columns  as c2
)

SELECT * 
FROM LargeTable
WHERE RowNumber % 10 = 0 --select 1 out of 10
GO

--OPTION 2: Create a view and loop though your batches
CREATE VIEW dbo.vLargeTable AS(
SELECT  RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY  c1.object_id)  --ORDER BY Primary Key
        ,c1.*
FROM    sys.columns as c1
        CROSS APPLY sys.columns  as c2
)
GO

SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;
DECLARE @batch      TINYINT = 10 
DECLARE @iteration  TINYINT = 0 

WHILE @iteration < @batch
BEGIN

    SELECT @iteration
            ,* 
    FROM dbo.vLargeTable
    WHERE RowNumber % @batch = @iteration    --select 1 out of 10

    SET  @iteration = @iteration + 1        
END
```